# COUNT(1) in DB2

Tags: database, count, db2

I have query where there is COUNT(1) in select statement.
I want to know what does it return. COUNT(*) will return the number of rows but COUNT(1) I have no idea. I tried to execute one statement in DB2 but got error saying COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST IS NOT VALID.

Comment: They will return the same value.  From a performance standpoint one may be faster than the other... I've not tested this on DB2.  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000001942084 appears to have, and indicates * is faster... but this http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?996966-count(1)-versus-count(*) contradicts that...  I would think the count(1) would be faster... but no real evidence.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col

Answer (score 1):

Post your SQL statement.

I suspect you have something like

```
select customer, count(1)
from salesHistory
```

In which case, DB2 isn't complaining about `count(1)` which is perfectly valid; but it's complaining because you've got a aggregate function in the select list along with a non-aggregate column.  In order to do that, you have to include a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select customer, count(1)
from salesHistory
group by customer
```